# How to apply conditional formatting to number with % sign in Plotly dash?

Tags: datatables, plotly, plotly-dash, conditional-formatting, plotly-python

I have table with last 20 columns with numbers with % sign, how can I format the negative numbers to have red background and positive to have green. My table is a filtered table and has the following code

```
return dash_table.DataTable(
            id='result-table',
            columns=[{'name': col, 'id': col, 'type': 'numeric', 'format': Format(precision=2, scheme=Scheme.fixed, symbol=Symbol.yes, symbol_suffix='%')} 
                if col in filtered_df.columns[-20:] else {'name': col, 'id': col} 
                for col in filtered_df.columns],
            data=filtered_df.to_dict('records'),
            style_header=style_header,
            style_cell=style_data
            )
```

I tried the following but all of the cells in last 20 columns are green

```
style_data_conditional = [{'if': {'column_id': col}, 'backgroundColor': 'green', 'color': 'white'} 
                          if col in filtered_df.columns[-20:] and col != 'Date' and row[col] >= 0 else 
                          {'if': {'column_id': col}, 'backgroundColor': 'red', 'color': 'white'} 
                          if col in filtered_df.columns[-20:] and col != 'Date' and row[col] < 0 else {} 
                          for col in filtered_df.columns for row in filtered_df.to_dict('records')]


return dash_table.DataTable(
    id='result-table',
    columns=[{'name': col, 'id': col, 'type': 'numeric', 'format': Format(precision=2, scheme=Scheme.fixed, symbol=Symbol.yes, symbol_suffix='%')} 
             if col in filtered_df.columns[-20:] else {'name': col, 'id': col} 
             for col in filtered_df.columns],
    data=filtered_df.to_dict('records'),
    style_header=style_header,
    style_cell=style_data,
    style_data_conditional=style_data_conditional
)
```